# Accessing a list on a separate method in a separate class in python

Tags: python, list, class, variables, methods

I have a problem with accessing a variable in a method from a another class.

I will simplyfy my problem as below, There are three main class that I use, I will only put two classes otherwise it might over complicate things.

```
from C import*
Athlete = C()

class A(object):

   def Runner(self,runNumber):

       Athlete.Calculation(runNumber):
       NumofLaps = Athlete.GetLaps #this is a list so NumofLaps will be a List
```

class C is a separate class which I have not included here, all it does is return a list stored in the calculation method. 
Above class A is the class that I want to access using class Main. as below,

```
from A import*
RunnerList = A()
class Main.py

   def RunnerNumber():
       number=1
       RunnerList.Runner(number)
       number = number + 1
       #code to access the NumofLaps List goes here
```

The problem that I am facing is that the calling method requires an input while calling it. (ex : RunnerList.Runner(number)). this is crucial for the code and i really do not want to change it.

But is there any way that I can access "NumofLaps" List in class A, Runner Method, from Class Main under RunnerNumber Method.

For example:

```
 RunnerList.Runner(number).NumofLaps
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly access a variable inside a method, but you can pass it to the self of class A:

```
from C import*
Athlete = C()

class A(object):

   def Runner(self,runNumber):

       Athlete.Calculation(runNumber):
       self.NumofLaps = Athlete.GetLaps #this is a list so NumofLaps will be a List
```

You can then access your list by calling :

```
RunnerList = A()
RunnerList.Runner(number)
the_list_you_need=RunnerList.NumofLaps
```

Comment: Hi Harry, Thanks for the reply, but If I pass it to the self of class A do I have to write a separate method called def __init__(self):

Comment: No, the `self` is created by a method called `__new__()`, before the `__init__`. The `__init__` is just here to initialise your instance at the creation, but you don't have to implement it if you don't need an initialization.